# which is the best books for ordinary differential equation for beginner?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

which is the  best books for ordinary differential equation for beginner ?

Comment: I don't know whether it is the best, but have a look at Tenenbaum/Pollard.

Comment: Try [Coddington](https://books.google.de/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Ordinary_Differential.html?id=PwivyktplHUC&redir_esc=y) or [Tyn Myint U](https://books.google.de/books/about/Ordinary_differential_equations.html?id=7iHvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y).